# "<ret>" meaning?

Tags: serial, motor-controller, serial-bus

I'm attempting to use multicharacter serial commands in this [manual](http://uhv.cheme.cmu.edu/manuals/18011m.pdf) (page 18 in the pdf, 16 in the manual), but can't get them to work. When I'm trying to use the "GX " command to move to, say 100, I've tried: "G100", "GX 100", "GX100", "GX <100>", "G100 ", "GX 100 " and probably a few others, but none of these produce the desired result. I assume I'm supposed to do something with the 'ret' but the manual isn't very helpful on this. The connection and everything else is working because commands like "A", "<", ">", "CA", etc, work fine. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: `<ret>` is probably `return` ... the code sent when the return key is pressed, usually labeled `enter` on PC keyboards .... it is labeled `return` on old serial terminals

Comment: <ret> probably refers to the ASCII carriage-return character, with the hex value 0x0D. In a C-style string, you can express it as "\r".

Answer (score 3):

`<ret>` means the carriage return character. This is the equivalent of the 'enter' or 'return' key on a keyboard, and it corresponds to ASCII code 0x0D (decimal 13.)

What they're saying is each command is terminated by a carriage return.

Here's the ASCII code chart for reference: https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: "equivalent of the 'enter' key"  Not really, on some systems "enter" generates CR+LF, on others only NL (same ASCII code as LF).  CR code alone is really only associated with a "return-and-do-not-advance" key, not used by modern computers but still available as an option in most terminal emulators.

Comment: The interpretation of the keyboard 'enter' key is context dependent. For example, a terminal shell program will convert the keyboard 'enter', which is sent as <CR>, into an echo of <CR><LF>.

Comment: I suspect the software will work on any “enter”key emulation and ignore redundant  LF if sent after CR.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the manual, I'd say \$<ret>\$ should mean "carriage return."  That's ASCII character 13.

Send G1000 followed by a carriage return.

---

You may need to shut down and restart the machine.  The characters < and > enter some special mode that you may have trouble exiting.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the ret is for carriage return.
I would say, try the following (each ending with the carriage return)

```
G-100
G+100
```

See if either of those work.
Also try with a space after the 100.